# Run a job with pretty odd time planning Airflow

Tags: cron, airflow, scheduler, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have an Airflow DAG that needs to be run in certain times of the day that can't be modeled using a cron expression. The times are: 09:20, 17:10 and 23:59. Any sugestions? The DAG is already fully constructed and runs with no problem when schedule_interval=None and is triggered manually. Have been searching for days with no success.

Comment: A simple solution could be to place a `BranchPythonOperator` upstream in your DAG and evaluate there the conditions, if they are not met, set your ending task as next step.  You could check if the `execution_date` matches the times you are looking for and also check if it was triggered externally. Use `DagRun` object in the execution context to access this values.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there's unfortunately no way to do this. A workaround could be to make 3 DAGs, one for each time, and have each DAG trigger the real workflow (using [TriggerDagRunOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/trigger_dagrun/index.html#airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun.TriggerDagRunOperator)), which is defined in a 4th DAG with `schedule_interval` set to `None`.

That said, a lot of work is currently happening on [AIP-39](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-39+Richer+scheduler_interval), which is what you're looking for. You can track progress [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/projects/10).